# z-index issue in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to bring absolutely positioned elements/components on top of other components which are rendered after that .
I am using `scrollview` component

```
style:
        width: 300,
        height: 100,
        position:'absolute',
        top:30,
```

but other components are overlapping the scroll dropdown .
I changed top to Bottom but the components which were on the top of `scrollview` are not getting overlapped.

As I am new to this react-native and unaware of `reactjs` I am unable to figure out solution and terms to express my problem please help.
I have attached screen shot of my problem in the below image I have a society dropdown in `scrollview` component and area is another scrollview which is visible and overlaps the first component

[image]

Comment: Ran into same issue, did you found any solution/workaround?

Answer (score 3):

`zIndex` property is supported as of react-native version **0.29.0**. Check the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props.html#zindex).

> zIndex controls which components display on top of others. Normally, you don't use zIndex. Components render according to their order in the document tree, so later components draw over earlier ones. zIndex may be useful if you have animations or custom modal interfaces where you don't want this behavior.
>
> It works like the CSS z-index property - components with a larger
> zIndex will render on top. Think of the z-direction like it's pointing
> from the phone into your eyeball. See
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index for more
> details.
>
> On iOS, zIndex may require Views to be siblings of each other for it
> to work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and it came from the fact that the zIndex wasn't applied to the right component. For instance if you have the following:

```
class App extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
           <View style={styles.form}>
               <View style={styles.selectInput}>
                   <TextInput placeholder="Select something" />
                   <Dropdown />
               </View>
               <View style={styles.formInput}>
                   <TextInput placeholder="Stuff" />
               </View>
               <View style={styles.formInput}>
                   <TextInput placeholder="Other stuff" />
               </View>
           </View>
        );
    }
}
```

And you want your `Dropdown` component to go above the 2 form inputs below, **you need to add `zIndex: 100` to its container**, the View with `selectInput` style.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: React Native now does support the `z-index` property! https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html

== old answer ==

React Native does not have a `z-index` property. The z indices are determined by the order of your components. For example:

```
<View>
    <Image />
    <Text />
</View>
```

The `<Text>` will always be above the `<Image>`.

Comment: can u suggest any suggestion because my scrollview component is above the other one so how i order them so that they dont come above my scrollview??

Answer (score 1):

Add both of your dropdowns in separate views and give zindex:1 to the first view and zIndex:-1 to the second dropdowns view. It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

`zIndex` with `position` will work, without one of them will not work based on my experience.